# AC red wire placement on control board?

Tags: hvac

So a fuse(3) on my control board blew at the same time my ac capacitor did. I replaced the capacitor with the exact one that was on the old unit and when replacing the fuse noticed a stray red wire... This wire and the white one next to it goes all the way to my ac. When I stripped the wire back a bit and connected it to R (you can see in this picture)
[image: Control Board]

the ac finally turned on and everything seemed to run fine until I noticed the fan on the outside unit was never turning off. At first I thought stuck contoller but now I'm wondering if I messed up a wire choice?

Comment: Can you post a wiring diagram for the outdoor unit to your air conditioner?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved! If you notice there is a little copper wire on the other side of the yellow terminal that I thought was the yellow wire wrapping around but nope, that's the broken off part of red so to solve my issue I had to connect red to Y next to that yellow wire.

Just wanted to post an answer in case anyone else makes this mistake, apparently red wires can connect to non-red things... I was naive and ignorant.
 [image]